# handling google analytics with 301 redirects

Tags: google-analytics

I have setup my domain www.example.com.
On going to the site it checks if user is logged in or not and does a **301 redirect** to www.example.com/login via PHP header method.

But because of this redirect I am unable to setup my google analytics account. The site is not getting verified. How can I get the website tracking verified in such a situation.

How can one handle **301/302 redirects** to get tracked properly in google analytics. Please guide. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google analytics started tracking my data after 24 hours. After that the site also got verified in google analytics setup.
It seems the tracking info is not updated on real time basis. This was not because of 301 redirects in my site.